# Safari Browser Compatible Issues

Tags: css

I have this code. It working fine for all browser for windows but it's not appearing in Mac safari browser.

```css
.send_msg{
    background:#000;
    padding:20px;
}

.send_msg input[type="text"] {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: medium none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff inset;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="send_msg">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: please set up on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qgraysrc/

Comment: Every place it's working fine but on the Mac safari textbox is not appearing.

Comment: Please clear what is the exact question? Whats not working in safari?

Comment: you have no border, white shadow, white text, you realise that right?

Comment: @Websolutionexpert24 I'm pretty sure it is appearing, it's just everything is white!

Comment: text box is not appearing. text box with shadow not appearing.

Comment: Please look it..jsfiddle.net/qgraysrc

Comment: "text box with shadow not appearing." It's white on white!

Comment: If I click that jsFiddle, I see it with a black background, and the text box does appear. I assume it was edited to add a non-white background?

Comment: Please look that link and send me proper solution.I am struggling only for that issues.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually dear it's appearing fine on the windows with mozilla, chrome, other modern browsers but only text box is not appearing on mac safari browser but appearing black background.

Comment: It shows up on Safari just fine with the black background.

Comment: I am saying about only text box with shadow. It's rendering on the all modern browser's but only it's not appearing on the Mac Safari browser. Ok friends.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike  yes only black background is appearing on the mac safari browser.

Comment: @Alex Thomas I have all things cleared please check and help me.

Comment: @Websolutionexpert24, it's not clear at all. Its the expected behavior with the code you're using. It's rendering the same on all browsers. Maybe add some screen shots to the question showing the differences you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I appears the same on Safari version 7.1 (9537.85.10.17.1). Here is a screenshot of your jsFiddle:

[image]

**Update**

If you are using Safari 3, then `box-shadow` will not work. I don't think Safari supported it until version 5, or somewhere around there. I wouldn't expect anything remotely modern to work on 3.

Comment: Will check what's problem exact. but what's your version of safari?

Comment: Sorry, I added the version to my post. It is 7.1.

Comment: Ohk but it's not appearing on the safari 3. May you check it that why it is not appearing on that?

Comment: you're using Safari Version 3!?

Comment: If you are indeed using Safari Version 3. Its a 7 year old browser. It's not going to support box-shadow.

Comment: If you are using Safari 3, then `box-shadow` will not work. I don't think Safari supported it until version 5, or somewhere around there. I wouldn't expect anything even remotely modern to work on 3.

Comment: Thank you to all I will check it again on the all latest browsers.